# Custom tooltip or custom labels (chart.js 2)?

Tags: javascript, tooltip, chart.js, label

I need to get a chart like this and I have no idea how to get it.

[image: chart]

I've tried with custom tooltips but I need show them all of them at the same time. I've tryed as well with [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels) but the labels are inside the canvas and they appear cut.

Do I need to create a html tooltip for every data?

Any ideas?

Updated:

Here is my code:

```
options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    animation: {
        animateScale: true,
        animateRotate: true
    },
    cutoutPercentage: 60,
    circumference: 2 * Math.PI,
    showAllTooltips: true,
    tooltips: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plugins: {
        datalabels: {
            backgroundColor: function(context) {
                return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
            },
            borderColor: 'white',
            borderRadius: 50,
            borderWidth: 1,
            anchor: 'end',
            align: 'end',
            color: 'white',
            padding: 10,
            font: {
                weight: 'normal',
                size: '10'
            },
            formatter: function(value, context) {
                var percentageNum = context.chart.data.datasets[0].data[context.dataIndex]
                return percentageNum + '\n  %';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Can you paste you js code by which you are trying to render this chart?

Comment: datalabels is exactly what you want. either make your canvas bigger or your chart smaller.